# Service Fabric WebAPI Service hosted on Azure unreachable both via public IP and localhost

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to create an ASP.NET Core WebAPI Stateful Service that will be hosted on Azure and reachable from App Service applications. I have successfully created Service Fabric cluster via Visual Studio with default ports 80 and 83 specified and published my application on it. https://appname.region.cloudapp.azure.com:19080/Explorer/index.html is reachable and shows nodes and application in Healthy state.

```
    <Endpoint Name="ServiceEndpoint" Protocol="http" Type="Input" Port="8210" />
```

is my endpoint, specified in ServiceManifest.xml. The service contains a controller that is reachable via
 http://localhost:8210/9a81c1e2-6f46-4570-a2f9-dafc3e73d9bc/131670697090937724/8e909880-81f7-46e1-87e6-f8c3cf960249/api/values endpoint on local cluster. Nevertheless, all the tutorials and neighbouring Stack Overflow questions mention that the service should be acessible via regular localhost:8210/api/values link, but I receive 410 Gone status code.

I have manually added an HTTP Probe pointing to /api/values url and specifying 8210 port. After that, I've updated an existing Load Balancer rule to forward 80 (HTTP) port to 8210 back-end port and specified my Health probe.

The problem is, none of the expected URLs are reachable. All of the variants below return 404 after a long load time:

```
http://appname.region.cloudapp.azure.com/
http://appname.region.cloudapp.azure.com/api/values
51.136.XX.XXX/api/values
51.136.XX.XX:80/api/values
```

I'm using Kestrel as the server used by web host. My main concern, other than the unreachable public IP, is the localhost endpoint not working without the long data provided by Service Explorer. Perhaps the problem is not in the Azure Service Fabric configuration, but the service itself.

What may be the reason for that? Am I using wrong URLs?

**UPDATE:** I should probably clarify the problem only appears when I'm working with ASP.NET Core State**ful** Service template. I had no problems uploading an ASP.NET Core State**less** Service both to localhost and Azure and access all the api endpoints.

Comment: Just to exclude a port issue, add a rule to the load balancer that maps 8210 to 8210.

Comment: I am not able to add an additional rule that maps to 8210 because it's already mapped and the mappings have to be unique. Here are my current LB rules and Health probes: [link](https://imgur.com/a/xUE7L)

Comment: Use routeprefix and route for redirecting to specific api and concatenate route to the endpoint exposed by service fabric node. suppose **api/values/get** is your route, then go to stateful service deployed on to the service fabric check its endpoint. it might be look like **localhost:8030**. Then check with localhost:8030/api/Values/get

Comment: Just for information, we used Stateless service to expose endpoints or creating web apis and for backend logic we used stateful service in project.

Comment: Thanks for your advice; in fact, I have no problem with Stateless services - they work just fine. It's the Stateful template I can't get to publish or access via localhost (or Azure).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the built-in [Reverse Proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy#reaching-microservices-from-outside-the-cluster).

Make sure to pass the partition key & kind, to indicate the Stateful service replica you want to access.

`http(s)://<Cluster FQDN | internal IP>:Port/<ServiceInstanceName>/<Suffix path>?PartitionKey=<key>&PartitionKind=<partitionkind>&ListenerName=<listenerName>`

Your service would likely be accessible like this:

`http://appname.region.cloudapp.azure.com/myservice/api/values?PartitionKey=0&PartitionKind=Int64Range`

Partition key note:

> For a partitioned service, this is the computed partition key of the
>   partition that you want to reach. Note that this is not the partition
>   ID GUID. This parameter is not required for services that use the
>   singleton partition scheme.